# Merging two array elements into one array element in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge two arrays into one array as follows,

**Array1:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [sku] => KOG456
            [cart_id] => 2
            [name] => Young Money
            [slug] => young-money
            [route_id] => 47
            [description] => 
This is test song


            [excerpt] => 
            [saleprice] => 90.00
            [related_products] => 
            [images] => {"1c6b0883fc94c5f644497ec488cdf8cb":{"filename":"1c6b0883fc94c5f644497ec488cdf8cb.jpg","alt":"Test","caption":"","primary":true}}
            [seo_title] => 
            [meta] => 
            [enabled] => 1
        )

)
```

**Array2:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filename] => Beethovens_Symphony_No._9_(Scherzo).wma
            [title] => Young Money
            [size] => 599.26
        )

)
```

Expected array result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [sku] => KOG456
            [cart_id] => 2
            [name] => Young Money
            [slug] => young-money
            [route_id] => 47
            [description] => 
This is test song


            [excerpt] => 
            [saleprice] => 90.00
            [related_products] => 
            [images] => {"1c6b0883fc94c5f644497ec488cdf8cb":{"filename":"1c6b0883fc94c5f644497ec488cdf8cb.jpg","alt":"Test","caption":"","primary":true}}
            [seo_title] => 
            [meta] => 
            [enabled] => 1
            [filename] => Beethovens_Symphony_No._9_(Scherzo).wma
            [title] => Young Money
            [size] => 599.26
        )

)
```

How to merge these array elements into one array element ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
foreach ($origArray as $key => &$subArray)
    $subArray += $arrayToBeAdded[$key];
```

Where `$origArray` is your array which is to be merged into and `$arrayToBeAdded` the array you merge into.

Comment: Thanks bro. I got the result using your foreach loop.

Comment: Hi, I tried this code in both localhost and live. It works fine in localhost, but not run in live. I got this error "Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in". How to fix this error bro ?

Comment: @balajimca Are you sure that the operators are arrays? (If you have something lower than PHP 5.3, upgrade first)

Comment: Yes, operators are arrays only. could I know the supported PHP version of this operand? my live server is 5.2.+ version, not PHP 5.3. Is there any alternative solution to run in 5.2+  version?

Comment: @balajimca Why don't you simply upgrade? PHP 5.2 isn't supported anymore... But you could `foreach ($origArray as $origKey => &$subArray) foreach ($arrayToBeAdded[$origKey] as $key => $val) $subArray[$key] = $val;`

Answer (score 1):

User `array_merge_recursive()`:

```
$final = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Its not working to me bro. I want to get the result as one array element. but it merges the arrays and shows two elements in the array.

Comment: The recursive one actually does the opposite of array_merge. Okay, this is weird. :( Anyways, you got the solution from the other answer I suppose. Great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this little known overload of the `+` operator for arrays:

```
$result = $array1[0] + $array2[0]
```

Comment: This will not give expected output bro.

Answer (score 0):

Use function `array_merge($array1[0], $array2[0])` . Following is the example for the same

```
$array1 = array(0=>array('1'=>1,'2'=>2,'3'=>3));

$array2 = array(0=>array('4'=>4,'5'=>5,'6'=>6));

$result[0] = array_merge($array1[0],$array2[0]);

echo '<pre>';

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have unique keys, you could use something as simple as the `+` operator (union)...

For example:

```
$arr1 = [1=>'testing',2=>'stack',3=>'overflow'];
$arr2 = [4=>'something',5=>'else',6=>'here'];
$arr3 = $arr1 + $arr2;
print_r($arr3);

Results:
Array ( [1] => testing [2] => stack [3] => overflow [4] => something [5] => else [6] => here )
```

Answer (score -1):

For this php has multiple functions. You can use $arrays = array_combine($array1, $array2);.

[PHP.net - array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Hope it helped!

Comment: Elements of each array is not equal. So array combine will not give expected result bro.